# Show if folders contain files or not in python

Tags: python, directory

I have a folder containing subfolders and I'd like to check if these subfolders contain files or not.

Output should look like

C:...\2001 contains files

C:...\2002 contains no files

and so on.

so far, I only found advice on how to delete empty folders, but I want to keep them since they might be filled later.

(I started coding 2 months ago but the people at my company think I'm some kind of IT wizard so I'd be very thankful if someone could help.)

Comment: Include you code(what you have tried so far) in the question.

Comment: Having updated my answer, could you check if it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
from os import listdir

path = "C:.../"
subfolders = listdir(path)
folders_with_files = []

for subfolder in subfolders:
    if listdir(path + subfolder) != []:
        folders_with_files.append(subfolder)
```